# Highlight a possible drop target while dragging a shape/group in KineticJS

Tags: drag-and-drop, mouseover, kineticjs

I am using KineticJS for implementing a graphical editor. I would like to drag a KineticJS Group and drop it into another shape. So far so good, done binding the "dropend" event to a handler in the group.
But I would like to change color to the potential destination shape while hovering on it during dragging, so as to give evidence that it is a suitable shape for drop.
I can't see a way of doing it and I am not been able to find any help in Kinetic documentation. How could I do?

Thanks,
eca

Answer (score 0):

After some mumbling, I think I have found a solution:

```
  var aShape = new Kinetic.Shape(...);
  :
  aShape.on("dragmove", function(evt) {

    // Detect shapes under mouse position
    var pos = aShape.getStage().getUserPosition(evt);
    var collidingShapes = aShape.getStage().getIntersections(pos);
    :
    // If needed, filter out colliding shapes not suitable for drop
    :
    // Highlight drop target candidates, e.g. simulating a "mouseover"
    for (var iTarget = 0; iTarget < collidingShapes.length; ++iTarget)
        collidingShapes[iTarget].simulate("mouseover");

    // If you need to remove highlighting, keep track of previously
    // highlighted shapes and call simulate("mouseout") on those
    // not currently in the candidates set.
  });
```

Comment: Just a thought, but to avoid this potentially using up a lot of cpu, how about using a setInterval to check the intersections. Use the mouseover just to update shared variables with the setInterval. That way you can ensure that each time the function runs it has the correct data, but also throttle it down to a smoother refresh rate. On dragend, simply clearInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Though what you did is actually working, I find it very slow. What I did, was to replace the line 3142 of kineticjs (v4.0.1):

```
else if(this.targetShape && !go.drag.moving)
```

with

```
else if (this.targetShape)
```

and it works like a charm. The `mouseout` and `mouseover` events are now fired.
Anyway, I don't know why, but there had been a property of the stage object (shapedragging or so) which pointed to a potential target, but it had been removed.